# Вывод сгенерированного числа

Tags: php

Всем привет!

Число генерируется кодом:

```html
<?php echo mt_rand(100000000, 999999999); ?>
```

Как вывести одно сгенерированное число в разные участках страницы?
Благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php $a = mt_rand(100000000, 999999999);
echo $a;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $rn = mt_rand(10000000, 99999999);?>


<div><p>Нужное место: <?php echo $rn . '<br>' ?></p></div>
```